# What is the meaning People reached in Profile

Tags: discussion, support

In the new profile under the **Impact** section i can see something like **people reached**. In my profile it is showing as 68K.

So question here is what is the that **people reached** whats the stat behind it.

Comment: If you mouseover the stat, there's a tool tip that explains it.

Answer (score 5):

People Reached signifies the total amount of pagevisits to your questions and highly-upvoted answers. It roughly shows the total amount of people you helped, directly or indirectly, through your questions or answers.

As mentioned in the comments, if you hover your mouse pointer over the People Reached, you can see a tooltip which explains it like the way below

[image]