# Does edits to questions and answers on other OPs get accounted for in my IMPACT calculation?

Tags: discussion, activity-tab, people-reached

I'm just curious about the IMPACT section.

[image]

To understand how the impact is calculated, I've read other posts like:

1. [How is impact calculated in the profile view](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293947/how-is-impact-calculated-in-the-profile-view)
2. [What is the meaning People reached in Profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290724/what-is-the-meaning-people-reached-in-profile)
3. [What does "people reached" signify and how is it calculated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290491/what-does-people-reached-signify-and-how-is-it-calculated)
4. [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here) (In this one, I literally searched for the word `edit` and found some comments that say it does have an impact and some that said it doesn't have an impact)

Now I'm confused as to whether edits to others' questions or answers have any change in my IMPACT.

Could someone please enlighten me regarding this?

Comment: The algorithm is defined in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here Anything not mentioned there doesn't count.

Comment: @RobertLongson, thanks :) But I'm still confused. I've edited the question.

Comment: I know that “anything that gets measured gets optimized”. But I think the bigger picture here is: please don’t make a thing of maximizing that number. You can glance at it and feel pride, but trying to deliberately max it out is misguided. Focus on making the site high quality, in any way you can. All good things flow from that

Comment: I'm sure that edits don't affect impact, and I'm quite [an editor](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So as suggested by [Robert](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson), I had a look at [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here)

As I was not able to properly understand whether or not they consider Editing on others' posts, I asked the same in a Comment.

And [Jaydles♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147336/jaydles), who's a Moderator, EVP of Culture and Experience at Stack Overflow and the OP of the post [commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here?noredirect=1#comment1037883_244534) with:

> @SiddAjmera, no, it doesn't. It'd be awesome to incorporate how editing, reviewing and other tasks contribute, but today it's limited to how many times your useful posts have been viewed.

So to answer my own question, Editing on others questions or answers don't have any impact on your IMPACT.